# Fix QML Camera's frame rate and change it resolution

Tags: android, qt, qml, qtandroidextras

Can it possible to fix frame rate and change resolution of `Camera`? Tried to use

```
  viewfinder.maximumFrameRate: 10 
  viewfinder.minimumFrameRate: 10
```

and

```
   viewfinder.resolution: Qt.size(640, 480)
```

no effect, they are simply being ignored.

How can I access the QML `Camera` from Android's Java side (I mean in `QtActivity` class)?
What does Qt use for creating `Camera` on Android devices?

Fixing frame rate is very important for current project, according to RTMP settings on server side.

Comment: When I set the min & max rates my VideoOutput component goes completely black. I would really like to find a solution to this as the performance of the camera is really poor once you get up to 5 or 6 preview windows.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as of [this bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42525) from 2014 Qt does not support setting the frame rate on linux and they have no plans to do so. I'm guessing this also applies to Android.